# Does having blender installed on a HDD over a SSD affect rendering time?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have Blender installed onto my hard drive instead of my SSD. I am experiencing some long render times, and I was wondering how much this would affect that.

I have no issues with performance or lag when using the software, just long render times.

Also as a follow up should I move all my textures and HDRIs n stuff to my SSD, or is keeping them on the HDD ok?

Comment: Everything needed for a blend file gets loaded into ram, so the only benefits an ssd would offer over a hdd is the initial load up speed when you first open the file and choose Material Preview or Rendered Preview (forcing it to load all the textures). It might also impact the loading of new textures, but differences are negligible unless you're working with a lot of hi-res (4k-8k) textures. Render speed is almost entirely dependent on cpu (and gpu, if applicable).

Comment: Hi :). An SSD can really help when rendering animations - since Blender loads data from disk for each frame again. But Blender 2.93 will introduce *persistent data*, which makes my point moot...